# Texture using ms3d not rendering on samsung galaxy

Tags: android, opengl-es

As I m beginneers in Android OpenGl Es.
I am working on 3D project,when I run project on G1 android phone, texture is rendering on Screen. But With Same code is  run on Samsang Galaxy, Texture has not been displayed. Screen is displayed Black. I don't understand what should do. plz tell me solution if anybody know.

I have This Egl configuration used.

```
public int[] getConfigSpec() 
{
    int[] configSpec = 
    {
        EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,16,
        //EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE,0,
        EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
        EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
                    EGL10.EGL_NONE

    };
```

Then no ms3d Texture was dispalyed.Only blackscreen  was diaplayed. 
After  I modified code then to then texture was getting displayed in White. 
    public int[] getConfigSpec() 
    {
        int[] configSpec = 
        {
            EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,16,
            //EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE,0,
            //EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
            //EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
            //EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
            ,
            EGL10.EGL_NONE

```
    };
```

public void sizeChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
    {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

```
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);                        
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf( -0.1f,0.1f,-0.15f,0.15f,0.55f,1000.0f);
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -296);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);                         // Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();    
}
```

Can Anybody tell what need to be Changed. How to set getConfig for samsang Galaxy (480*800)

Thanking you.

pratibha

Comment: More information, such as code and screenshots, might help a lot ...

Comment: This class of bug is almost always due to not explicitly setting some GL property or other (e.g. texture mode). Different drivers occasionally have slightly different defaults. Yeah, you should really post code so we can see what you haven't done.